# Pass `List<List<Bitmap>>` as ref

Tags: c#, list, ref

I'm making a Space Invaders game in C#, using `Bitmap` to store images for the invaders, bombs, etc.
What puzzles me:
I have an abstract class `GameObject` representing the simple elements in the game:

```c#
protected Bitmap image;
protected Rectangle bounds;
protected Rectangle movementBounds;

public GameObject(ref Bitmap image, Point position, Rectangle movementBounds)
{
    this.image = image;
    this.bounds = new Rectangle(position, new Size(image.Width, image.Height));
    this.movementBounds = movementBounds;
}
```

Than a `ShieldSegment` class representing a single square of a `Shield`, which has four images for various stages of damage:

```c#
private int timesHit = 0;
private IList<Bitmap> alternateImages = new List<Bitmap>();

public ShieldSegment(ref List<Bitmap> images, Point position, Rectangle movementBounds)
    : base(ref images.First(), position, movementBounds)
{
    alternateImages = images;
}
```

And a `Shield` class which represents the whole shield as a list of segments:

```c#
private IList<ShieldSegment> segments = new List<ShieldSegment>();

//fill, upper left, upper right, lower left, lower right
public Shield(ref List<List<Bitmap>> images, Point position, Size imageSize)
{
    //upper row
    Point startPosition = position;
    segments.Add(new ShieldSegment(ref images.ElementAt(1), startPosition,new Rectangle(startPosition, imageSize)));
    startPosition.X += imageSize.Width;
    segments.Add(new ShieldSegment(ref images.ElementAt(0), startPosition,new Rectangle(startPosition, imageSize)));
    startPosition.X += imageSize.Width;
    segments.Add(new ShieldSegment(ref images.ElementAt(0), startPosition, new Rectangle(startPosition, imageSize)));
    startPosition.X += imageSize.Width;
    segments.Add(new ShieldSegment(ref images.ElementAt(2), startPosition, new Rectangle(startPosition, imageSize)));
    //middle row
    startPosition = position;
    startPosition.Y += imageSize.Height;
...
```

I need to pass the list elements as references, since (and sorry if I'm wrong) it would be wasteful to store the images anew for each segment and shield. It works fine when passing a single reference to `Bitmap`, but here I get `a ref or out argument must be an assignable variable`.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to pass the list elements as references

You're not really being clear here. The list reference is just passed, by value by default but by reference if necessary. When you *access* the list, you'll get a reference. However, this code:

```
public ShieldSegment(ref List<Bitmap> images, Point position, 
     Rectangle movementBounds)
    : base(ref images.First(), position, movementBounds)
{
    alternateImages = images;
}
```

suggests you may not understand how parameter passing works in .NET to start with:

- You're not changing the value of the `images` parameter to start with, so you don't need to use `ref`
- It makes no sense to use `ref` with an argument which is the result of a method invocation... what do you *expect* it to do?

I suggest you read my [article on it](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html), as well as my article on [reference types and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html), which should clarify things.

Comment: All of them are classes. I'm gonna read it right away. One more bit for the question - I have the game up and running, passing the images without the ref keyword, but I've noticed that memory usage goes up to about 80 Mb, which seems way too much. So I thought that it is because each instance of a game object stores a copy of the image.

Comment: @AlexandarŽivkovič: No, that's not the way it works. Each Game object will have a *reference* to a Bitmap object. Whether each one has a reference to the *same* object or not depends on how you're populating them... 80MB doesn't sound *particularly* huge, if you've got quite a lot of graphics etc.

Comment: This is how I'm populating them:
http://pastebin.com/C8yU6Bh4
Well there are 55 invaders on start, each has 2 images about 300 bytes each, one tank (one image, same size) and 4 shields with 12 segments each, each segment has 4 images per 150 bytes. But it still seems like a lot, especially since it jumps all the time, depending on the number of things on screen.

Answer (score 3):

A `List` is a reference type. That means the value of the `List` variable itself, `images`, is a reference. You can pass it without `ref`!

Just be careful not to treat it as an `out` argument in the function though. For instance, don't assign things to `images` with `images = new List...` That won't work.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? If I drop the ref keyword from the `ShieldSegment` and `Shield` I get invalid arguments error.

Comment: You did remove the `ref` keyword from both the function definition and the function calls, right?

Comment: Yes, in `Shield` and `ShieldSegment`, but I need it in the `GameObject` constructor, because of classes representing the tank, invaders, etc.

Comment: What? There are no lists in the GameObject constructor. Is this still about getting lists to work as function arguments, or are you trying to solve some other problem now?

Comment: My bad - I have removed the `ref` keyword from `ShieldSegment` and `Shield`, but I need it in the `GameObject` constructor (`GameObject(ref Bitmap image, ...`), because of other classes. I suppose I'll just change the `ShieldSegment` implementation a bit, so that it won't extend `GameObject`. I can't pass `images.First()` in `ShieldSegment`, because it does not match the argument in `GameObject`, since that expects a reference.